# Network detection when on the London Underground

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, offline

What is the best way to detect if a user has network service when a user has entered the London Underground?

I've tried the following;

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).isAvailable() || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).isAvailable())
{
    // Application online
}
```

I've also tried getting the network level, but this seems to return the last level before the tube has entered the underground.

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Comment: ...what's this got to to with the London Underground? o_Ô

Comment: Can this question be simplified to "how do I detect when the user has lost coverage?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

from thread [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)